# I want to add camera button for answering questions on my website?

Tags: camera, web

https://electronics2electrical.com I have this site I want to add a camera function to it so user can take and upload the images directly on Answers like handwritten notes or mathematical problems photo etc. how can I add this camera function for mobile users .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, camera upload is simple file upload (like any other) so it should work with simple

```
<input type="file" name="upload" />
```

However, in HTML5 there is support for directly opening camera to take a photo instead of choosing from gallery using something like

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="capture" capture="camera">
```

You can test different modes of operation using these pages:

1. https://anssiko.github.io/html-media-capture/
2. https://mobilehtml5.org/ts/?id=23

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Thanks for response ....but how can I send the taken image to server..will it automatically send to server?

Comment: @ZeeshanSheikh you need to wrap everything in <form> element and add a submit button and then accept the file server-side and move it to wherever you want it to be stored. I believe this is currently outside of the scope of StackOverflow. There are numerous examples online how to do this, for example if your site is in php you can google "php file upload tutorial" and follow any of the examples, i.e. https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472551